# JavaScript looping through an array inside a object inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a list of games(objects) inside a object, which is inside an array of players. I'm trying to check which object inside the array is the current user to than go in the games array and a print out the objects property.

Go through PlayerList to find currentUsers

```
for (let i = 0; i < model.playerList.length; i++) {
        if (model.currentUser == model.playerList[i].userName)
        //Go Through games from the player to print the game information
        {
            for (let i = 0; i < model.playerList[i].game.length; i++) {
                html += `<div>
           <p> Spillnr: ${model.playerList[i].game[i].gameNumber}</p>
           <p> Ord: ${model.playerList[i].game[i].word}</p>
           <p> Dato: ${model.playerList[i].game[i].date}</p>
           <p> Forsøk: ${model.playerList[i].game[i].attempts}</p><hr>
            </div>`;
            }
        } else { console.log('ok') }
```

I'm getting the properties of game from different objects inside playerList instead of only getting from the currentUser.

HELP PLEASE

Comment: Please provide the original object and the expected result

Comment: its a list(playerList) of objects (player)  with a list(game) of objects (the info from the game) `model.playerList = [
  {    userName: 'MasterLetters',
   age: 27,
   password: '123456',
   game: [{
      gameNumber: 1,
      date: '15/01/2022',
       word: 'bukse',
       attempts: 9,
           },
            {
                gameNumber: 2,
                date: '17/01/2022',
                word: 'kakse',
                attempts: 7,
            },
        ]

    },`   the result expected is to print the game info for each player as long as theyr logged in currentUser`

Answer (score 1):

I think the root of your issue is that you're using the same index `i`  for both the `playerList` and `game` arrays. When you change `i` to go through the games, you're also changing which player you're getting information from.

I'm guessing your `for` loop was intended to iterate through the list of games, not the list of players, so before you can run that loop, you need to find the player in the `playerList`

I would recommend using `find()`

```js
// Find the player with the username that matches currentUser
// If the player is found, thisPlayer will contain the player object
let thisPlayer = model.playerList.find(player => model.currentUser == player.userName);

// If we fould a player, iterate through the games and add HTML for each one
if(thisPlayer) {
    thisPlayer.game.forEach((game) => {
        html += `<div>
        <p> Spillnr: ${game.gameNumber}</p>
        <p> Ord: ${game.word}</p>
        <p> Dato: ${game.date}</p>
        <p> Forsøk: ${game.attempts}</p><hr>
         </div>`;
    })
}
```

Comment: That was a good solution and it worked for the first user, but if i tried to to login now as a different user the entire page crashed and i cnt even open the console, no idea whats happening

Comment: has loop never stops now when i try to login as a different user, than it crashes everytinho.. tried do to a console log on the login function now jst to check, ans is infiniting looping

Comment: You probably need to add some exception handling. Maybe the user's game array is empty or the objects don't have the right keys. Make sure the game key exists and that there are items in the array.